# wp_capabilities deleted from my wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

my wordpress website users ( admin and editors...), roles permissions resets and when I want to login I saw this error message "you don't have permission to access"!
and all users (wp_capabilities) meta has been deleted from database !!!

any body have solution?

Comment: do you have database backups? How many users has this affected?

Comment: yes have backups.

all users meta tag (capabilities) are deleted